# Complex MongoDB find queries on large documents in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

How do I make a MongoDB query using BasicDBObjects in Java, when I wish to find all documents that contain an array of nested documents, where one of those nested documents meets all the specified criteria?

Taking the example data:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"blood_0",
      "type":"O",
      "list":[
         {
            "firstname":"John",
            "lastname":"Smith",
            "zipcode":"12345"
         },
         {
            "firstname":"John",
            "lastname":"Hamilton",
            "zipcode":"54627"
         },
         {
            "firstname":"Ben",
            "lastname":"Brick",
            "zipcode":"12345"
         },
         {
            "firstname":"William",
            "lastname":"Tell",
            "zipcode":"15487"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"blood_1",
      "type":"AB",
      "list":[
         {
            "firstname":"Mary",
            "lastname":"Smith",
            "zipcode":"12345"
         },
         {
            "firstname":"John",
            "lastname":"Henry",
            "zipcode":"54624"
         },
         {
            "firstname":"Jacob",
            "lastname":"Tell",
            "zipcode":"19283"
         },
         {
            "firstname":"William",
            "lastname":"Dirk",
            "zipcode":"15999"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

If I only want to return the objects that contain a contact in the list that meets the criteria of **firstname = William**, **lastname = Tell** how would I go about doing that?  The queries I am doing are not grouping the criteria, so I would get two results where I actually only should be getting one.

How would I do the same query but also checking for **type = AB**, as well as the other criteria, which would return no results?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-an-array-of-documents

Comment: I know how the query is supposed to work if I was going to query MongoDB, I don't know how to recreate it in Java using BasicDBObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator. It restricts the query operators to a single element within the array of values.

In the shell your query will look like:

```
db.people.find( { list : { $elemMatch : { lastName:"Smith", firstName: "John" } } } )
```

To add the blood type:

```
db.people.find( { 
       type : "AB",
       list : { $elemMatch : { lastName:"Smith", firstName: "John" } } 
} )
```

This gets a bit verbose using the Java Driver.

```
DBObject elemMatch = new BasicDBObject();
elemMatch.put("lastName","Smith");
elemMatch.put("firstName","John");

DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.append( "type", "AB");
query.append( "list", elemMatch);
```

Pass that query to one of the find() methods on the collection and you should get the documents you are looking for.

Note that the $elemMatch query operator will return the entire document, including all of the elements in the array.  There is a similarly named projection operator to limit the array elements returned to only those matched.

HTH - Rob.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. I really think your model is utterly wrong. Nested arrays which potentially grow indefinetly are bad for multiple reasons:

1. If the document exceeds it's [padding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/storage/#record-allocation-strategies) when new members are written to this array, the document needs to be migrated within a data file. That is a pretty costly operation and you want to prevent it as much as you can.
2. BSON documents are limited to 16MB. So per blood type you could only have a limited number of people.
3. All queries tend to be a bit more complicated, the according code more bloated and hence slower.

So how to do it? Take these documents:

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  firstName: "Mary",
  lastName: "Smith",
  zip: "12345",
  bt: "AB"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Smith",
  zip: "12345",
  bt: "0"
}
```

With indices set like

```
db.people.ensureIndex({lastName:1,firstName:1})
db.people.ensureIndex({bt:1})
```

on the MongoDB shell, you can get what you want with

```
db.people.find({ lastName:"Smith", firstName: "John"})
```

or

```
db.people.find({ bt: "AB" })
```

This query for example translates to the following

```java
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost");

DB db = client.getDB("yourDB");
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("yourCollection");

BasicDBOBject query = new BasicDBObject("bt","AB");
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);

try {

  while( cursor.hasNext() ) {

    System.out.println( cursor.next() );

  }

} finally {

    cursor.close();

}
```

You might find the [MongoDB introduction for working with a Java driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/) interesting.

Comment: That data is simply an example to provide a visual of what I was asking as I am not permitted to post the data model I am working with, the arrays are not indefinite. I did not create the data model, nor do I have the time or permission to make changes to it. I am simply asking how to write the query using the Java Mongo drivers to successfully get the correct results I am looking for.

Comment: Well, I have put an example and a link to the docs. As a side note, I'd like to add that the model is _everything_ in MongoDB. So I'd like to point you to the [modelling docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

Comment: Your example shows a basic find query, and you reorganized my data... My question is related to finding documents based on searching nested arrays of objects against criteria.  If you need a  better idea of what my data is, imagine a collection of customer profiles, each document has an array of contact method objects.  I want to search against those contact method objects using multiple criteria.

Comment: Mind reading the links I provided you with? Or the basic documentation? ;) I am asking because if you did, you should have come along using the so called ['dot.notation' for searching in arrays of subdocuments without specifying an array index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index). So you'd query for `list.firstname` and `list.lastname`, to stay within your example (which you should have marked clearly as artificial).